# To find norm of $T, T(x) = x+M$

Tags: normed-spaces

We are given that $M$ is a closed linear subspace of a normed linear space $N$,  $T $ be the natural mapping from $N\to N/M$ as mentioned in title,  we need to show that $T$ is continuous Linear transformation with norm $\le 1$.

$x_n$ be any sequence converging to $0$ then $\lim T(x_n) =\lim[x_n+M] =M$, which is the $0$ element in $N/M$,  hence $T $ is continuous,  is my logic correct?

I am not able to calculate the norm, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you are correct, but you need to justify $\lim(x_n + M) = M$! That is what you want to prove, you cannot use it.

To prove the norm-bound (and hereby prove continuity), do as always. First recall the definition of the norm in $N/M$:

> $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{x+M} := \inf_{m\in M} \norm{x+m} $

As $0 \in M$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{Tx} &= \norm{x+M}\\ 
            &\le \norm{x+0}\\
            &= \norm x
\end{align*}
Hence $\norm T \le 1$.

---

To complete the sequential argument - if you want to - you also have to use that by definition of $\norm{x_n + M}$ we have $\norm{x_n + M} \le \norm{x_n}$. Hence 
$$ \norm{Tx_n} = \norm{x_n + M} \le \norm{x_n} \to 0, $$
that is $T$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it is enough to prove the bound for continuity of $T $, but could you please tell me how to solve the sequential argument? Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for your reply